# How to change img src in home-made theme, using Wordpress` live customizer?

Tags: images, paths

I have a home-made slider based on css that is sliding my 'hero' section. I would like to be able to change img src from wordpress panel control, rather than changing html.

Comment: This depends on your theme, better contact its author.

Comment: There is no theme, I am building from scratch :)